# The view students.views.addgrregister didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

**ValueError at /students/addgrregister/**
i am trying to add students in gr_register but its giving an error due to this error the code is not working i also upload the template (addgrregister.html) kndly tell me where is the issue in these pages

**models.py**

```
class gr_register(models.Model):
Gender_Choices = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('FM', 'Female'),
)
Status_Choices = (
    ('P', 'Present'),
    ('FM', 'Left'),
)
gr_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
date_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
classes_A = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="classes_A", default=1, verbose_name="Class of Admission")
sections_A = models.ForeignKey(Sections, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sections_A", default=1, verbose_name="Section of Admission")
gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Gender_Choices)
classes_C = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="classes_C", verbose_name="Current Class")
sections_C = models.ForeignKey(Sections, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sections_C", verbose_name="Current Section")
address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="Home Address")
area_code = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Area")
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Status_Choices, default='P')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('gr_no',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
def addgrregister(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = gr_registerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = gr_registerForm()
    return render(request, 'students/addgrregister.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField, ModelForm
from .models import *

class gr_registerForm(ModelForm):
classes_A = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Classes.objects.all())
sections_A = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sections.objects.all())
classes_C = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Classes.objects.all())
sections_C = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sections.objects.all())
area_code = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Area.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = gr_register
    fields = '__all__'
```

def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
    forms.ModelForm.**init**(self, *args, **kwargs)

**addgrregister.html**

```
{% extends 'authenticate/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="text-center">ADD GR_REGISTER</h4>
    <hr/> 
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'addgrregister' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" class="col-2 col-form-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Add GR_REGISTER</button>
    </form>
 <br/><br/>
</div>  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't return anything if `request.method == 'POST'` but `form.is_valid()` is `False`.

Comment: how can i do this can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing returned when form is not valid. I think you try like this:

```
def addgrregister(request):
    form = gr_registerForm(request.POST or None)  # it initates a form. If the request type is POST, then there will be a dict available with posted data in request.POST. If request is not POST, then the form will initiate with empty data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():  # Form valid checks if the submitted form is valid or not. If not, it will store errors in the form. When that form is passed to template, it will show errors in html
            form.save()  # It will store data in DB
            return redirect('home')
    # when for is invalid, it will show the error in the form
    return render(request, 'students/addgrregister.html', {'form': form})
```

### Update

Show form errors in template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" class="col-2 col-form-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-10">
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.errors }}  // <-- Updated here
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: i am new in python can you please tell me ?? about this ?

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar I have added few comments to the code. Please have a look.

Comment: i have multiple foreignkeys in gr_register in  models.py and these foreign keys are connected with forms.py like ModelChoiceField. thes connections are true or not please tell me

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question. Basically the foreignkeys are connected in Models. Form just uses that model to render the html form. Connections are created whenever you save the form.

Comment: can i add foreignkeys in forms.py ? in the way of ModelChoiceField ??

Comment: Foreignkey is related to DB, hence that connection needs to be made in models. Form does not make any FK connection. Here in forms, you are overriding the form field with `ModelChoiceField`. I don't think its necessary.

Comment: i am trying to add data in data base with forms but it give me an error like this (ValueError at /students/addgrregister/) and this (The view students.views.addgrregister didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead)

Comment: Please try my answer, and see if there is any error. thanks

Comment: i copy your code now its not giving error but , but when i click add button still data is not adding

Comment: The form is not validating. Can you please share your template code in your question?

Comment: i have uploaded template (addgrregister.html)

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar I have updated my answer with a template with form. Please use that, it will show errors of your form. Then it will be clear to you why the data is not being stored in DB. hope it helps